# How to make an object follow another object at a certain distance?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make a game similar to slither.io. I am only at the first steps of trying to make my snake (which is build by number of sections (circles)) move in the direction of the mouse. I succeeded moving the head section of the snake in the direction of the mouse and I want the rest of the sections moving in the path of the head, like in the original game, but that the distance between each section will be as I want ("sectionsdistance"). Any ideas how can I make that? 
https://jsfiddle.net/nzemc3ws/2/

```js
function Snake(x, y, r) {
    this.headpos = createVector(x, y);
    this.r = r;
    this.body = [];
    this.additionalsections = 0;
    this.sectionsdistance = 2 * r * 0.5;
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        this.body.push([this.headpos.x, this.headpos.y + i * this.sectionsdistance]);
    }

    this.update = function() {
        var prevheadpos = this.headpos.copy();
        var velocity = createVector(mouseX - width / 2, mouseY - height / 2);
        velocity.setMag(3);
        this.headpos.add(velocity);
        for (var i = this.body.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i == 0) {    // Second Section
                this.body[i][0] = prevheadpos.x;
                this.body[i][1] = prevheadpos.y;
            }
            else {
                this.body[i][0] = this.body[i-1][0];
                this.body[i][1] = this.body[i-1][1];
            }
        }
    }

    this.show = function() {
        fill(212, 239, 255);
        stroke(186, 229, 225);
        strokeWeight(4);
        for (var i = this.body.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ellipse(this.body[i][0], this.body[i][1], this.r * 2, this.r * 2);
        }
        ellipse(this.headpos.x, this.headpos.y, this.r * 2, this.r * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance of creating a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes i added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

The trick with this is to use a list, add to the front with every move, and remove from the end with every move EXCEPT when the snake is growing. Doing this, you don't actually have to move any of the body parts between the head and the tail